# How to use htaccess in nginx , datalife engine (cms) and

Tags: nginx

I installed Datalife Engine (cms) on my nginx server , all thing was working great actually until
visiting html catagories from this cms that showed me 404 not found. I thought its for htaccess file and i didnt know that we cant use htaccess in directory like apache. so i checked the htaccess file and these are the converted (apache to nginx https://winginx.com /en/htaccesscodes):

```
    # nginx configuration by winginx.com

index index.php;

location /page {
  rewrite ^/page/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /index.php?cstart=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$1&cstart=$2&seourl=$4 break;
  rewrite ^/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$2&news_page=$1&seourl=$3 break;
  rewrite ^/page,([0-9]+),([^/]+).html$ /index.php?do=static&page=$2&news_page=$1&seourl=$2 break;
}

location / {
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&cstart=$5&news_name=$6&seourl=$6 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5&seourl=$5 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/print:page,([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?mod=print&subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5&seourl=$5 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_name=$4&seourl=$4 break;
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$4&news_page=$2&cstart=$3&seourl=$5&seocat=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$2&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?mod=print&news_page=$2&newsid=$3&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$2&seourl=$3&seocat=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$1&seourl=$2 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/*$" /index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page/([0-9]+)/*$" /index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&cstart=$4 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/*$" /index.php?year=$1&month=$2 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/([0-9]+)/*$" /index.php?year=$1&month=$2&cstart=$3 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/*$" /index.php?year=$1 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/page/([0-9]+)/*$" /index.php?year=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^.]+)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=cat&category=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  }
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?do=cat&category=$1 break;
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^.]+)/rss.xml$ /index.php?mod=rss&do=cat&category=$1 break;
  }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^/]+).html$ /index.php?do=static&page=$1&seourl=$1 break;
  }
}

location /print {
  rewrite ^/print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?mod=print&news_page=$1&newsid=$2&seourl=$3 break;
  rewrite ^/print:([^/]+).html$ /index.php?mod=print&do=static&page=$1&seourl=$1 break;
}

location /tags {
  rewrite ^/tags/([^/]*)/*$ /index.php?do=tags&tag=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/tags/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=tags&tag=$1&cstart=$2 break;
}

location /xfsearch {
  rewrite ^/xfsearch/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=xfsearch&xf=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/xfsearch/(.*)/?$ /index.php?do=xfsearch&xf=$1 break;
}

location /user {
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/rss.xml$ /index.php?mod=rss&subaction=allnews&user=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/*$ /index.php?subaction=userinfo&user=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?subaction=userinfo&user=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/news/*$ /index.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/news/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/news/rss.xml/*$ /index.php?mod=rss&subaction=allnews&user=$1 break;
}

location /lastnews {
  rewrite ^/lastnews/*$ /index.php?do=lastnews break;
  rewrite ^/lastnews/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=lastnews&cstart=$1 break;
}

location /catalog {
  rewrite ^/catalog/([^/]*)/rss.xml$ /index.php?mod=rss&catalog=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/catalog/([^/]*)/*$ /index.php?catalog=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/catalog/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?catalog=$1&cstart=$2 break;
}

location /newposts {
  rewrite ^/newposts/*$ /index.php?subaction=newposts break;
  rewrite ^/newposts/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?subaction=newposts&cstart=$1 break;
}

location /favorites {
  rewrite ^/favorites/*$ /index.php?do=favorites break;
  rewrite ^/favorites/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=favorites&cstart=$1 break;
}

location = /rules.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=rules break;
}

location = /statistics.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=stats break;
}

location = /addnews.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=addnews break;
}

location = /rss.xml {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?mod=rss break;
}

location = /sitemap.xml {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /uploads/sitemap.xml break;
}
```

and this is my default config (default) :

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(doc|sql|setup)/ {
    deny all;
    }

location ~ /phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }
}


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 192.168.1.107;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}

}
# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

how should i fix 404 not found and its possible to fix it with htaccess !?
so if its possible , how can i use this configuration without any error?!
photo :[404 not found html pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14PXO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# nginx configuration

index index.php;

location /page {
  rewrite ^/page/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /index.php?cstart=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$1&cstart=$2&seourl=$4 break;
  rewrite ^/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$2&news_page=$1&seourl=$3 break;
  rewrite ^/page,([0-9]+),([^/]+).html$ /index.php?do=static&page=$2&news_page=$1&seourl=$2 break;
}

location / {
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&cstart=$5&news_name=$6&seourl=$6 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page,([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5&seourl=$5 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/print:page,([0-9]+),(.*).html$" /index.php?mod=print&subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_page=$4&news_name=$5&seourl=$5 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*).html$" /index.php?subaction=showfull&year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&news_name=$4&seourl=$4 break;
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$4&news_page=$2&cstart=$3&seourl=$5&seocat=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$3&news_page=$2&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?mod=print&news_page=$2&newsid=$3&seourl=$4&seocat=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$2&seourl=$3&seocat=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?newsid=$1&seourl=$2 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/*$" /index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page/([0-9]+)/*$" /index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&cstart=$4 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/*$" /index.php?year=$1&month=$2 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/([0-9]+)/*$" /index.php?year=$1&month=$2&cstart=$3 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/*$" /index.php?year=$1 break;
  rewrite "^/([0-9]{4})/page/([0-9]+)/*$" /index.php?year=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^.]+)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=cat&category=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  }
  rewrite ^/([^.]+)/?$ /index.php?do=cat&category=$1 break;
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^.]+)/rss.xml$ /index.php?mod=rss&do=cat&category=$1 break;
  }
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/([^/]+).html$ /index.php?do=static&page=$1&seourl=$1 break;
  }
}

location /print {
  rewrite ^/print:page,([0-9]+),([0-9]+)-(.*).html$ /index.php?mod=print&news_page=$1&newsid=$2&seourl=$3 break;
  rewrite ^/print:([^/]+).html$ /index.php?mod=print&do=static&page=$1&seourl=$1 break;
}

location /tags {
  rewrite ^/tags/([^/]*)/*$ /index.php?do=tags&tag=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/tags/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=tags&tag=$1&cstart=$2 break;
}

location /xfsearch {
  rewrite ^/xfsearch/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=xfsearch&xf=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/xfsearch/(.*)/?$ /index.php?do=xfsearch&xf=$1 break;
}

location /user {
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/rss.xml$ /index.php?mod=rss&subaction=allnews&user=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/*$ /index.php?subaction=userinfo&user=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?subaction=userinfo&user=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/news/*$ /index.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/news/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?subaction=allnews&user=$1&cstart=$2 break;
  rewrite ^/user/([^/]*)/news/rss.xml/*$ /index.php?mod=rss&subaction=allnews&user=$1 break;
}

location /lastnews {
  rewrite ^/lastnews/*$ /index.php?do=lastnews break;
  rewrite ^/lastnews/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=lastnews&cstart=$1 break;
}

location /catalog {
  rewrite ^/catalog/([^/]*)/rss.xml$ /index.php?mod=rss&catalog=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/catalog/([^/]*)/*$ /index.php?catalog=$1 break;
  rewrite ^/catalog/([^/]*)/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?catalog=$1&cstart=$2 break;
}

location /newposts {
  rewrite ^/newposts/*$ /index.php?subaction=newposts break;
  rewrite ^/newposts/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?subaction=newposts&cstart=$1 break;
}

location = /feedback.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=feedback break;
}

location = /register.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=register break;
}

location /favorites {
  rewrite ^/favorites/*$ /index.php?do=favorites break;
  rewrite ^/favorites/page/([0-9]+)/*$ /index.php?do=favorites&cstart=$1 break;
}

location = /rules.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=rules break;
}

location = /statistics.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=stats break;
}

location = /addnews.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?do=addnews break;
}

location = /rss.xml {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?mod=rss break;
}

location = /sitemap.xml {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /uploads/sitemap.xml break;
}
```

Comment: How to use and add it in configuration?